# packages/Net/UserAgent/Detect/APC.php flagged as malicious by Wordfence Firewall

Tags: wordpress, php, security

Our Wordpress firewall Wordfence has flagged packages/Net/UserAgent/Detect/APC.php as possibly a malicious file.  Based on past experience, I assume this is a false positive.  However, I posted it here in case it is a real problem.

**Filename:** wp-content/civicrm 5.18.3/civicrm/packages/Net/UserAgent/Detect/APC.php

**File Type:** Not a core, theme, or plugin file from wordpress.org.

**Details:** This file appears to be installed or modified by a hacker to perform malicious activity. If you know about this file you can choose to ignore it to exclude it from future scans. The matched text in this file is:

The issue type is: **Suspicious:PHP/antibotInclude.C.7882**

Description: **Inclusion of an antibot file, often used in phishing kits**

Answer (score 1):

What I believe it's flagging based on the "description" line in your post is probably that the UserAgent tool could be used by bad people to get information about a browser, possibly to look for versions or configurations with known security holes to exploit. But it doesn't seem to be used in CiviCRM as far as I can see, and the APC.php subclass file all it does is store the results in the APC cache if you're using that. I wonder if the whole Net/UserAgent folder could be removed from Civi.

UPDATE: It looks like the file will be removed in civi version 5.22: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/272

Comment: Same issue.  Also looking for a definitive answer.  I've posted a question on CiviCRM Chat / Town Square.  Nothing definitive there yet.

Comment: I can definitely say it is not a virus. As noted in the answer all the file does is store the results of UserAgent Detect in the APC cache. But you're right as to why wordfence is flagging it, no I don't have a definitive answer to that.

Comment: I believe I can safely tell WordFence to ignore the file.  I'll do that, and keep an eye out here and on CiviCRM Chat.  Thanks.

Comment: [history for that code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/commits/master/Net/UserAgent) says it hasn't been touched in years, [search for usage in packages](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/commits/master/Net/UserAgent) shows no usage, and [search for use in core](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=net_useragent&type=) indicates no use in core.  burn it!

Comment: @chris-burgess Seamus has put up a PR to remove it. Can you comment there too? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/272

Comment: This just popped up again.  Did the module get restored somehow? I checked, and the folder/file is definitely there in CiviCRM 5.20.0.

Comment: Hi, as noted in the answer it was removed in 5.22. So 5.20 still has it but you can remove it manually.